# Syntax error in query on an Access database from Delphi

Tags: ms-access, delphi-xe2

I keep getting the same error when I try and get info from my MS access database. Below is my coding.

```
var      
iTemp, iX, iY, k : Integer;
sDate : String;

begin

  iTemp := 0;
  DB.Close;
  DB.SQL.Add('SELECT Count(UserID) AS Total FROM tblResults;');
  DB.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := pID;
  DB.ExecSQL;
  DB.Open;

  iTemp := DB.FieldByName('Total').AsInteger;

  if iTemp = 0 then
    ShowMessage('Sorry but we do not have any test results for you. Take a test and check your result !')
  else
  Begin

    DB.Close;
    DB.SQL.Add('SELECT Mark,DateTested AS Total FROM tblResults WHERE UserID=:ID;');
    DB.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := pID;
    DB.ExecSQL;
    DB.Open;

    for k := 1 to iTemp do
    Begin

    iX := k;
    iY := DB.FieldByName('Mark').AsInteger;
    sDate := DB.FieldByName('DateTested').AsString;

    Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(iX,iY,sDate,clTeeColor);

    DB.Next;

    End;

    Db.Close;
  End;
```

The error is

> Syntax errpr. in query expression 'Username="SELECT Count(UserID) AS Total FROM tblResults'

I really do not undertand this error. Please help me get this thing working.

Comment: Don't you need to do a `DB.SQL.Clear;` before you try to `DB.SQL.Add` the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Delphi (only MS Access), but one thing in your code still looks strange to me:

Your error message says that the error occurs "in query expression 'Username="`[the SQL string from your code]`.

You passed the SQL string to your query with this code:

```
DB.SQL.Add('SELECT Count(UserID) AS Total FROM tblResults;');
```

As you are using `DB.SQL.Add('...')` (and not something like `DB.SQL = '...'`), I suspect that maybe `DB.SQL` already contains something at the beginning of your code.

Where else should the `'Username=` part come from?

Comment: I just added a DB.SQL.Clear before I added the actual query.